# SOAP client in IIS cannot access web services in Tomcat

Tags: web-services, iis-7, tomcat7

I have IIS (`localhost:443`) and Tomcat (l`ocalhost:8080`) both running on my local machine. The Tomcat contains Java web services and I can remotely debug it in Eclipse IDE. I have an application installed in my IIS and when I access the page of that application, it requests a web service in Tomcat.

The problem is that when I try to load the page (the one deployed in IIS), my Eclipse won't go to the break point, meaning no request was retrieved on the Tomcat side.

But when I try to execute a request using SoapUI, Tomcat receives it and it enters my breakpoint in Eclipse. (meaning that the web services are accessible)

I cannot debug the application in IIS so I cannot determine why it can't call the web service.

Do I need to setup Windows Firewall for it? I'm just running those apps in my local machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your IIS app pointing properly to the Tomcat WS?

Comment: I edited C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyProject\Web.config and I put the wsdl locations there. I cannot debug the app on IIS and that file is the only thing i edited

Comment: I got it working. My problem was permission issues in c:\windows\temp directory. I found my answer here http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/unable-to-generate-a-temporary-class-result1-error-cs2001-source-file-cwindowstempfilenamecs-could-not-be-found-error-cs2008-no-inputs-specified/

Comment: Why don't you post the solution as an answer here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. My problem was permission issues in c:\windows\temp directory. I found my answer here http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2008/02/06/unable-to-generate-a-temporary-class-result1-error-cs2001-source-file-cwindowstempfilenamecs-could-not-be-found-error-cs2008-no-inputs-specified/